# How to sort an array using a searched text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I searched for "hr001" and it returns all index having "hr001". This is ok.
But I want to sort this array using searched text("hr001").

Look at given code. Here returns first and last element of this array when I searched "hr001" and array order is: "code": "SFHR001", "code": "HR001".

Since I searched for "hr001" and it fully matches to "code": "HR001", so i want to show "code": "HR001" as first element

```js
var items = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "SFHR001",
        "property": "8''",
        "description": "Half Round",
        "productGroup": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Steel Files",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "MR004",
        "property": "7''",
        "description": "Polished",
        "productGroup": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Pliers",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "HR001",
        "property": "7''",
        "description": "Fine Polished",
        "productGroup": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Hand Reveter",
        }
    },
]

search = (item, searchedText) => { 

  return item["code"].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchedText.toLowerCase()) > -1
    
}


var ac = items.filter((item) => {
  return search(item, 'hr001');
});

console.log(ac);

// var sortWithInputText = ac.sort(..........................)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort typeahead suggestions with the exact input at top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704250/sort-typeahead-suggestions-with-the-exact-input-at-top)

Comment: You want to match exact word or want to have partial matching as well ?

Comment: @HereticMonkey no. I want to sort an array using my searched text

Comment: @Md.RobiUllah, Do you want like this? https://codepen.io/manmur/pen/zYxgJLz

Comment: `ac.sort((a,b)=> a.code.toLowerCase().indexOf('hr001') - b.code.toLowerCase().indexOf('hr001'))` something like this will do the work

Comment: @CodeManiac I want partial matching. Then i have to sort it according to my searched text

Comment: I would use some form of scoring mechanism,.. You could base this on the length of the search and the result, the nearest length goes to the top.

Comment: That's exactly what the answers to that question do. Exact matches are moved to the top, As the matches diverge, they are moved farther away from the top. Did you try the answers?

Comment: @HereticMonkey no. I will try this brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of logic to decide what is the closest,..

One simple example might be to base on length, so were the result length and length of search term are near, these go to the top.  You could do more fancier scoring than this, but you will need to decide what logic this pertains.  eg. There is even something called a soundex algorithm, you might want to merge with this etc.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex

But using the simple length test as a guide, below is a simple example.  It also falls back to simple string comparing if the score's of each item are equal.

```js
var items = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "SFHR001",
        "property": "8''",
        "description": "Half Round",
        "productGroup": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Steel Files",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "MR004",
        "property": "7''",
        "description": "Polished",
        "productGroup": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Pliers",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "HR001",
        "property": "7''",
        "description": "Fine Polished",
        "productGroup": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Hand Reveter",
        }
    },
]

search = (item, searchedText) => { 

  return item["code"].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchedText.toLowerCase()) > -1
    
}

const searchTerm = 'hr001';

function score(a) {
  return Math.abs(searchTerm.length - a.code.length);
}


var ac = items.filter((item) => {
  return search(item, searchTerm);
}).sort((a, b) => {
  //sort by score, if equal fall back to compare.
  return score(a) - score(b) ||
    a.code.localeCompare(b.code);
});

console.log(ac);

// var sortWithInputText = ac.sort(..........................)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
items
.filter(el => el.code.toLowerCase().indexOf('hr001')>-1)
.sort((a,b)=> a.code.toLowerCase() < b.code.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for a 'sort by field' function.

JS's `Array.prototype.sort` function takes an optional parameter that is it's 'sort algorithm'. This is just a function that takes 2 params and returns `-1` if the first param should be indexed first, `1` if the second should be indexed first, and `0` if they are equal.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp

```
function sortObjectByField(a, b, field) {
  if (a[field] < b[field]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a[field] > b[field]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
};

items.sort((a, b) => sortObjectByField(a, b, 'code'));
```